# How to load base64 image data from the database inside html image tag using jinja python

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

How can I populate my card view with images being received from the database using Jinja? I have written my SQL statement to fetch data from my database table called candidates. One of the columns holds blob data which is in base64. I am trying to have the candidate image displayed on the HTML template. Unfortunately, with my code below the images are not showing.
Below is my Python code for saving into the database

```py
    def convertToBinaryData(filename):
        # Convert digital data to binary format
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    
            # rb means open the file in binary mode (read/write using byte data)
            binaryData = file.read()
            # encode the file to get base64 string
            file = base64.b64encode(binaryData)
        return file
    @app.route("/express-interest", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def express_interest():
        if request.method == "POST":
            surname = request.form["surname"]
            other_name = request.form["other_name"]
            political_party = request.form["political_party"]
            posittion = request.form["position"]
            government_office = request.form["government_office"]
            email_contact = request.form["email_contact"]
            manifesto = request.form["manifesto"]
            passport_upload = request.files["passport_upload"]
            #working on the image
            filename = secure_filename(passport_upload.filename)
            passport_upload.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            img = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)
    
            imagebinarydata = convertToBinaryData(img)
            # encode the file  to get base64 string
            file = base64.b64encode(imagebinarydata)
            # print(imagebinarydata)
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO `candidates`(`username`, `other_name`, `political_party`, `government_office`, `position`, `email_contact`, `manifesto`, `passport`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            with connection:
                cursor.execute(insert_query,(surname,other_name,political_party,government_office,posittion,email_contact,manifesto,file))
                connection.commit()
            return render_template("express_interest.html")
        else:
            return render_template("express_interest.html")
```

below is the Python code fetching data

```py
    @app.route("/candidates")
    def candidates():
        select_query = "SELECT * FROM candidates"
        cursor.execute(select_query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
        return render_template("candidates.html", rows = rows)
```

below is the HTML code

```html
      {% extends 'index.html'%}
        {% block content %}
        <h2 class="text-center">{% block title %} candidates {% endblock %}</h2>
        <div class="row">
            {% for row in rows %}
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{row[8]}}" class="card-img-top" alt="candidate image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                        <p class="card-text">{{row[2]}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is mostly correct, but there are a couple of issues in your code that might be preventing the images from displaying correctly.

1. **Base64 Encoding in Flask**: When you save your image to the database,
   you are encoding it as Base64. When you fetch the image data from
   the database and pass it to the template, it's already
   Base64-encoded. Therefore, you should not encode it again with
   `base64.b64encode`. You should pass the binary data as is.
2. **Image Format**: Ensure that the images stored in the database are in a
   format (e.g., JPEG, PNG) that is supported by HTML's `<img>` tag. You
   are using `"data:image/jpeg;base64,{{row[8]}}"`, which suggests that
   your images are in JPEG format. Make sure this matches the actual
   format of the images stored in the database.

**Python code for fetching data:**

```
@app.route("/candidates")
def candidates():
    select_query = "SELECT * FROM candidates"
    cursor.execute(select_query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template("candidates.html", rows=rows)
```

**HTML template:**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2 class="text-center">{% block title %} candidates {% endblock %}</h2>
<div class="row">
    {% for row in rows %}
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ row[8].decode('utf-8') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="candidate image">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ row[1] }}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{ row[2] }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

- Removed the unnecessary `base64.b64encode` on `file`.
- Added `.decode('utf-8')` to decode the Base64 data in the `src` attribute
  of the `<img>` tag.

With these changes, the images should be displayed correctly in your card view based on the Base64 data stored in your database. Ensure that the image format (JPEG) matches the format of the images you are storing in the database.

### UPDATE :

there might be an issue with the way the Base64-encoded data is stored in the database or retrieved from it
Here are some steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Check the Database**: First,
   ensure that your images are correctly stored in the database. You
   can verify this by examining a sample entry in your database to
   confirm that the image data is indeed a valid Base64-encoded string.
2. **Data Type**: Make sure that the column in which you store the
   Base64-encoded image data has an appropriate data type, such as
   `LONGTEXT` or `BLOB`, to accommodate the data.
3. **Retrieve Data**: When fetching data from the database, confirm that
   the data you receive (e.g., `row[8]`) is a valid Base64-encoded
   string. You can print this data to the console to check its
   integrity.
4. **Image Format**: Ensure that the image format in your database (e.g.,
   JPEG, PNG) matches the format specified in the `src` attribute of the
   `<img>` tag (e.g., `data:image/jpeg;base64)`. Consistency is crucial
   here.
5. **Encoding/Decoding**: Double-check that you're not accidentally
   encoding or decoding the Base64 data multiple times, as this can
   lead to issues.
6. **Browser Console**: Check your browser's console for any error messages
   related to image loading. This can offer insights into any problems
   with the image data.

By following these steps and verifying the integrity of your data at each stage, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue.

Comment: still no image is showing even after adding the .decode('utf-8') as you have suggested.

Comment: check last updated steps

Comment: I had encoded the file twice by mistake. Inside the candidates route and on the converttobinary() function. I have followed your updated steps and it now works. Thanks

Comment: Well, Happy to hear that.